# Try catch while loop Java

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch, field

hi guys so apparently I tried using try-catch in a while loop and using static field. My situation is I create a scanner to get user input and use String split method to try and split the string into array of just 2 by spaces (" "). Somehow, I used try-catch for when user enter just string the second 2 array will be null and it will be ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Apparently when I used this try-catch at first when I enter 2 string delimited by a space it prints out both the array but somehow in the next line when I just type 1 string which means that thee second string array will be null it prints out the second string array as well which apparently the second string array it was the string that I typed before.
What I want is when I type only want String array the second String array will appear null. 
Its better if you try the code, thanks.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FinchTest {

    static String str1;
    static String str2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String userInput= scan.nextLine();

            String[] SpaceSpliter = userInput.split(" ");
            str1 = SpaceSpliter[0];
            str2 = SpaceSpliter[1];
            System.out.println(str1+str2);

        } catch ( java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            if(str2==null) {
                System.out.println(str1+str2);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(str1+str2);
            }
        }


    }while(true);

    }

}
```

I think the problem is because of the global field

Comment: What you are want is unclear. Please review your question and be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare your String variables within *do-while* loop.

EDIT 1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
do {
    String str1 = new String();
    String str2 = new String();

    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput= scan.nextLine();

        String[] SpaceSpliter = userInput.split(" ");
        str1 = SpaceSpliter[0];
        str2 = SpaceSpliter[1];
        System.out.println(str1+str2);

    } catch ( java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        if(str2==null) {
            System.out.println(str1+str2);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(str1+str2);
        }
    }


}while(true);

}
```

EDIT 2:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
do {
    String str1 = null;
    String str2 = null;

    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput= scan.nextLine();

        String[] SpaceSpliter = userInput.split(" ");
        str1 = SpaceSpliter[0];
        str2 = SpaceSpliter[1];
        System.out.println(str1+str2);

    } catch ( java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        if(str2==null) {
            System.out.println(str1+str2);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(str1+str2);
        }
    }


}while(true);

}
```

Comment: but then it wouldbe an error in the catch part because its not a global variable

Comment: this means that i cant str 1 and str 2 variable in the catch part

Comment: Declare them outside the 'try' block, but within the 'do' block

Comment: thank you man, but i still have one problem which that even when I tried your edited code when str was not entered it wasn't null I think it was str2="". because I had an if statement which says if str2 is null execute this code but apparently it does not execute so it means for some reason str will not be null

Comment: If you want str2 to be 'null', then only declare the String variables, but do not initialize them. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

there is no second element which is null when you type only one string, there is just no second element , that array will be of size 1

what you should do is

```
  // follow naming conventions , don't name is SpaceSpilter 

    for(String s : spaceSpliter)
       System.out.print(s + " ");
```

It will work for any length of string , and you don't need to use any try catch

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is a screenshot when loop iterates for the second time, str2 = SpaceSpliter[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYeLf.png); is the line where you get an exception and at that time str2 has previous iterations value. That is why your result is the concatenation of the current iteration's str1 value and previous iteration's str2 value.

Comment: thanks for the comment. So the thing is if I put in 1 value of string which it would be an error and will go to the catch part where it prints out str 1 and str 2 will be null. However, this action appears in the second iteration where str array 1 and str array 2 is filled I will get the value of str array 2 which is what I don't want. Is there anyway you help solve this problem thanks.

Comment: Declaration of str1 and str2 in a loop would help if it does not bother you. String str1, str2 = null; in loop itself. Before try-catch block.

Comment: thank you man, but i still have one problem which that even when I tried your edited code when str was not entered it wasn't null I think it was str2="". because I had an if statement which says if str2 is null execute this code but apparently it does not execute so it means for some reason str will not be null

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment String str1, str2 = null; would help you as stated by @rajan_saini.98